# sharepoint 2013 developer installation

Tags: 2013

I'm trying to install a development install for sharepoint 2013 in my machine and I'm following the steps in http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx , but I dont want to buy a domain, how can I use a fake domain that redirects to my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to buy a domain, you can use for example portal.com or any other you want, just on the machine: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-create-a-domain-in-windows-server-2008/

Then you can point (host hack) the domain to local host on your dev machine: http://www.hacktrix.com/how-to-edit-hosts-file-in-windows-vista